# How can I set column name as the name of .csv file's column?

Tags: php, csv

I have a code which creates a `.csv` export of my table. Here is my code:

```
public function export(Request $request){

    header('Content-Type: application/excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');

    $tb_name_alias = $request->tb_name;
    $convert_alias_to_table_name = array('person' => "App\\persons");
    $tb_name = $convert_alias_to_table_name[$tb_name_alias];
    $arr = $tb_name::all()->toArray();

    $newarr = array();
    $size_of_outer_array = sizeof($arr);

    For ( $i = 0; $i < $size_of_outer_array; $i++ ) {
        $newarr[] = implode(",",$arr[$i]);
    }

    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    foreach ( $newarr as $line ) {
        $val = explode(",", $line);
        fputcsv($fp, $val);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

It works as well, But when I import it again, it looks like this:

[image]

As you see, the column names aren't real .. they are `col1`, `col2`, etc ..! But I need to set some names as those column names. Like `id`, `name`, etc ..!

How can I do that?

Comment: please refer below link which suits your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810599/in-php-to-dynamically-get-table-name-and-fields-from-csv-file-and-import-to-mysq

Comment: Can you show one row of data you get to $newarr. print_r($newarr);

Comment: @user3099298 here is the array: `$newarr =array('1,John,22','2,Jack,30','3,Peter,14');`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($fp, array('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3'));


 foreach ( $newarr as $line ) {
        $val = explode(",", $line);
        fputcsv($fp, $val);
    }
    fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Well your approach doesn't set any name for columns .. it just create a row as the first one. I don't want that